# Mozilla Firefox: Untrusted Connection

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, ssl

I am attempting to document an issue that I recently encountered.  Can someone please confirm the following for me?  Or make any corrections?  I want the information that I document to be completely accurate.  I am attempting to document why Firefox displays a warning while Chrome and Internet Explorer do not.  It may have something to do with the caching of certificates or it may be as I have described below.  I don't see technical documentation regarding this issue so your help is appreciated.  If you can also point me to technical documentation from Microsoft and/or Google that confirms this that would help as well.  I encountered an issue where the SSL Chain was broken and it was only Firefox that displayed the Untrusted Connection warning but it was only if Firefox had not previously cached the Intermediate Certificates from another website.  I had to resolve the issue by deleting the certificate entirely both CRT and Activation and then re-installing the Certificate using the CA-Bundle from the Certificate Authority.

Text:

There are numerous reasons for encountering the message: "This connection is untrusted."  However, you may find the issue is due to missing Intermediate Certificates in the SSL Chain.  The missing Intermediate Certificates may be the RSA Domain Validation Secure Server Certificate and the RSA Certification Authority Certificate.  Google Chrome and Microsoft Internet Explorer appear to not require the Intermediate Certificates in the SSL Chain.  These browsers appear to only require the initial SSL Server Certificate and the Root Certificate Authority Certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have complete understanding of how the certificates are validated. In case of IE (Chrome uses Windows Certificate Storage, the same as IE) the intermediate certificate is already installed on your computer, that's why IE and Chrome don't complain. Firefox doesn't have that certificate installed and Firefox has own certificate storage. Strictly speaking, Firefox (or any other client) is not required to have any intermediate certificates - it's the site owner's job to include any intermediate certificates to the list which is presented to the client upon connection.

Comment: I rewrote as follows: "There are numerous reasons for encountering the message: "This connection is untrusted."  However, you may find the issue is due to missing Intermediate Certificates in the SSL Chain.  The missing Intermediate Certificates may be the RSA Domain Validation Secure Server Certificate and the RSA Certification Authority Certificate.  Google Chrome and Microsoft Internet Explorer use the Trusted Root Certification Authorities Store on the client computer to obtain the Intermediate Certificates in the SSL Chain.  Firefox uses the Mozilla CA Certificate Store."  Any changes?

Comment: @reversehalo Any  certificate can be missing ,  not just the ones you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

I alse had this horrible annoying problem and I just managed to fix it.

I'm using Replay Media Catcher (it captures video/audio from the internet), and I found out that when the program is open everything is fine, so I searched google and found this:
https://replaymediacatcher.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202520104-Why-did-I-lose-internet-connectivity-after-using-RMC5-

And so what fixed it for me was going to:
Internet Options >> Connections >> LAN settings >> Unchecking the third option "Use a proxy server for your LAN" (here's a screenshot to help - http://oi59.tinypic.com/206hml0.jpg)
And also disabling the option "Monitor HTTPS/SSL" in Replay Media Catcher.

I hope this helps :)